# What is the reason for an error 'eth0: Transmit timeout' in dmesg?

Tags: linux, networking, dmesg

On a gentoo Linux system the `dmesg` output shows something like the following repeatedly:

```
eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0x45E1
eth0: Transmit timeout, status 0c 0005 c07f media 10.
eth0: Tx queue start entry 18  dirty entry 14.
eth0:  Tx descriptor 0 is 0008a5ea.
eth0:  Tx descriptor 1 is 0008a5ea.
eth0:  Tx descriptor 2 is 0008a5ea. (queue head)
eth0:  Tx descriptor 3 is 0008a5ea.
eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0x45E1
```

and the output of `ethtool -S eth0` is

```
NIC statistics:
     early_rx: 0
     tx_buf_mapped: 0
     tx_timeouts: 137
     rx_lost_in_ring: 0
```

However, on an identical system with identical ethernet card and identical Linux and identical kernel there is no such error visible. How to find out the reason for this error message?

*Speculation*: Could it be some firewall issues, then the Linux system is trying to copy something to a different system? Any other network-related issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen this error message in a very long time. Are you on old hardware/software?

In any way, the trick to make it work is to disable acpi, the Advanced Configuration and Power Interface. Please do not confuse this with apic, the Advanced Programmable Interrupt Controller.

The way to do it is to change the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

into

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=off ro quiet splash"
```

in (on my Ubuntu system) /etc/default/grub. In Gentoo, I do not know, but I am sure you may find something strictly equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I (i) cannot find a file on gentoo which contains the specified line and (ii) I do not see the problem on an identical system, which almost to absolute certainty has the exact same internal Linux configuration (concerning settings for boot, kernel, etc. )

Comment: @Alex Perhaps you are not on Grub? Also: if you really believe the two systems are identical, then no use in asking: the fault lies in the hardware. But are you sure the two systems are identical?

Comment: I believe this issue to come from the network outside the system. I sometimes see problems when transfering data to an outside server, resulting in a counter increase for `ethtool -S eth0`. Do you totally disagree, or do you think this could be the reason? The actual systems are identical, but they are used in dfferent places with different network settings (outside of the actual Linux/hardware system).